# Simplex method with zero value constraints

Tags: linear-programming

The usual problem is to maximize some linear function
$f(x_0, x_1 ... x_n)$
subject to linear constraints
$g_i(x_0, x_1 ... x_n) \leq b_i$.

My question is: What happens when all (or most) of the $b_i$ are zero?

You start with a basic solution which is degenerate, and then hit the problem of deciding which row to use for your pivot, since all the $b_i$ are zero.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are $x_i$ nonnegative?